# How to return something within addEventListener in Scala.js?

Tags: scala, scala.js

Let's say I have the following method:

```
  def registerBlurEventListener(blur: BlurEvent): Unit = {
    dom.window.addEventListener("blur", (e: FocusEvent) => {
      val myObj = BlurEvent.doStuff(blur)
      // How to return myObj?
    }}
  }
```

Returning `myObj` inside the `addEventListener` method is probably not possible. However, can this code be somehow rewritten in a way to get the value `myObj` without mutating `blur`?

Comment: You're probably going to have to mutate *something*, sadly -- the pattern of `addEventListener` doesn't provide much alternative, AFAIK.  Exactly what depends on the scope of the blur event...

Comment: @JustinduCoeur Thanks for the help! What would be the best practice here?

Comment: What do you want to *do* with `myObj`?

Comment: @sjrd Ideally I would return it and use it for further processing. After that, it will be sent to the server. I now restructured my code to something like this:
`var blur = BlurEvent()` then the `dom.window.addEventListener` and inside `blur = BlurEvent.doStuff(blur)` and in the end I just send it to the server.

Comment: Yeah -- in a callback-oriented system such as the DOM Event model, that's probably about as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `myObj` from `registerBlurEventListener` would not do you much good in most cases because you don't know at what point in time the blur event occurs, and that's really what you care about.

What you need is a value to represent the blur events fired in the future. You can use one of the streams / observables libraries like Monix or RxJS to create a stream of `FocusEvent`s in your method.

You can then pass around this stream as a value. You could subscribe to it and call `doStuff` on every new event that arrives. You can also map over the stream to create a new stream with transformed values. The exact combination depends on the streaming library you choose and on the desired outcome. Streams are typically lazy, so you need to subscribe to a stream if you want to run a side effect on every new value. (`doStuff` kinda sounds like a side effect). It's a bit too much to describe here in detail.

---

There are entire libraries for DOM manipulation using streams, observables, and reactive variables, for example: Outwatch, Binding.scala, Monadic-html. The keyword you're probably looking for is "functional reactive programming".

---

If you only care about a single blur event in the future, as opposed to a stream of such events, look into Javascript Promises which Scala.js does support. JS Promises are a lot like streams that only emit once and remember their emitted value.

Answer (score 0):

I am astonished nobody has answered this yet :) This is a prime use case for Futures.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Promise, Future}

def registerBlurEventListener(blur: BlurEvent): Future[MyObj] = {
  val promise = Promise[MyObj]()
  dom.window.addEventListener("blur", (e: FocusEvent) => {
    val myObj = BlurEvent.doStuff(blur)
    promise.success(myObj)
  }}

  promise
}
```

Use like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val myObj = registerBlurEventListener(???)
myObj.foreach(obj => println(obj))
```

A couple of caveats:

- Of course this does not return the value immediately, but it returns something you can again listen on.
- This only works if your event fires only once. Next time the listener fires, `promise.success` will throw an exception. If you expect to "return the value multiple times" you need something like reactive streams.